# Covariance group of the functional equation of an L-function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, mathematical-physics, riemann-hypothesis, l-functions

These last few days, I've been wondering whether one could consider the parameters/variables $\chi$ and $s$ a Dirichlet L-function depends on as coordinates such that the pair of transformations $(\chi\mapsto\bar{\chi},s\mapsto 1-s)$ defines an involutive isometry of the considered L-function. Indeed the functional equation thereof is: $$\Lambda(\chi,s)=\omega\Lambda(\bar{\chi},1-s)$$

with $\Lambda$ the complete Dirichlet L-function and $\vert\omega\vert=1$, so that $\vert\Lambda(\chi,s)\vert=\vert\Lambda(\bar{\chi},1-s)\vert$. Hence the "covariance group" of the functional equation should be isomorphic to $Z/2Z$.

Can this be used to get information about the location of the zeroes of the complete L-function, and thus, nontrivial zeroes of the (incomplete) L-function? Has such an approach of GRH related topics been considered so far?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgive me if this comes across as rude, but to me it sounds like you are making a trivial observation (the functional equation has "order two" in some vague sense) followed by asking if this will help prove GRH. So the answer is no. All this does is show that if you have a zero-free region near $\Re(s) = 1$, then you also have one near $\Re(s) = 0$, and if you have one for $L(s,\chi)$ then you also have one for $L(s,\overline{\chi})$. (Actually, this is not completely correct, but it's morally true.) But why should you expect this symmetry to give you anything stronger?

Comment: Because in some sense the functional equation determines the (complete) L-function which is itself entirely determined by the multiset of its zeroes through Hadamard factorization theorem.

Comment: In other words, I expect the nontrivial zeroes of a Dirichlet L-function to exhibit the same kind of symmetry as the one of the functional equation.

Comment: But this is trivial! If $\gamma + it$ is a zero of $L(s,\chi)$, then so is $1/2 - \gamma - it$, while $1/2 - \gamma + it$ and $\gamma - it$ are zeroes of $L(s,\overline{\chi})$. This follows trivially from the functional equation and the fact that $\overline{L(s,\chi)} = L(\overline{s},\overline{\chi})$. This is the extent that the functional equation tells you anything about the nontrivial zeroes of $L(s,\chi)$ and $L(s,\overline{\chi})$, however.

Comment: One should consider all the non trivial zeroes at the same time and their global structure rather than a single hypothetical zero off the critical line. My goal is to correctly define automorphisms of L-functions in a functorial way from this "covariance group" but there is still much work to be done.